# How to correctly read stdin in C?

Tags: c, stdin, ncurses

I want to write a app like [sgtpep/pmenu](https://github.com/sgtpep/pmenu) in C.

Then I start to look at the `ncurses` library. My first try is able to select the menu. Such as when I do `ls | ./a.out`, it should be able to show all the files, and highlight the first one, when I press <kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, it will change highlight different item accordingly.

The full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/delta4d/97ccaf7ccc440f9a177109708c1cc44b).

The program does not receive any keypresses. `mvprintw(n+1, 0, "%d\n", ch);` inside the loop always print `-1`.

Then I remove the unrelated code, and get the minimal example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buf[100];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int ch;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) puts(buf);

    ch = getch();
    printf("%d\n", ch);
    ch = getch();
    printf("%d\n", ch);
    ch = getch();
    printf("%d\n", ch);
    ch = getch();
    printf("%d\n", ch);

    return 0;
}
```

`ch` is always `-1`. I suspect the `stdin` is not clean, so I use `fflush(stdin)` after `fgets`, but it results the same.

So what is the correct way to read from `stdin`?

---

**UPD1**

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buf[100];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int ch;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) puts(buf);

    fflush(stdin);

    ch = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", ch);
    ch = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", ch);
    ch = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", ch);
    ch = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", ch);

    return 0;
}
```

I have modified the program, so it is not related to `ncurses` anymore, but when running `ls | ./a.out`, `ch` keeps showing `-1`.

---

**UPD2**

Use `newterm` to redirect `in` and `out` works.

```
FILE *fd = fopen("/dev/tty", "r+");
set_term(newterm(NULL, fd, fd)); // instead of initscr()
noecho();
cbreak();
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

print_menu(cur, n);

while (true) {
    ch = getch();

    if (ch == KEY_UP || ch == 'k') --cur;
    else if (ch == KEY_DOWN || ch == 'j') ++cur;

    cur = (cur + n) % n;

    print_menu(cur, n);
}

endwin();
```

Comment: I suspect this is an ncurses question, not actually a C question. The lowest-level API for reading in C on POSIX systems isn’t actually the C `fgets` method but the POSIX `read` system call. I don’t think that’s where the issue is, though. I think the issue is that the terminal is not in “raw mode”. I do not remember how to set terminals to raw mode, I think it varies by terminal, and I’m pretty sure ncurses has an initialization function which handles that kind of thing.

Comment: I don't see a "refresh()" in your print_menu().  For details of writing ncurses applications, look here:  http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html

Comment: @TonyB Thanks! This is a copy&paste error... I changed the code structure to make it clear, but forget adding `refresh()`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks! So how can I prevent `getchar()` reading `EOF`, but reading my keypresses?

Comment: @DavidBowling using `ncurses` is exactly where I came from. `getch()` is still showing `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to switch from *stdin* to curses in that way, you'll have to open the terminal device, e.g., `/dev/tty` when you're done reading the standard input.  Once you've opened the terminal, you can initialize curses using [`newterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm) (which has parameters for the input/output streams unlike [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr)).

For examples, see the [ncurses test-program](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/ncurses.c#L7240), or [dialog](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/master/util.c#L252).

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the program a little more, so it is not related to curses lib. But the problem still exists. Am I on the wrong way for getting input while the input is piped?

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I finally got what you mean. `newterm` works when there are multiple terminal.

Comment: yes it does, although mostly it's used for situations such as this.

Answer (score 0):

curses is an alternative to stdin.

The C model is that user composes a line in the console, which gives him line-editing capabilities. He can backspace and use the arrow keys to move around the line, until he's happy with it. Then he presses enter, and the program gets the entire line. The program then processes it and, usually, prompts for the next line.

curses takes over the keyboard so that it can be used as a key pad - you can have a little space invaders game with "z" meaning "left" and "x" meaning "right". Consequently, you shouldn't be trying to read from stdin at the same time, you will get characters, but the curses system will interact with them in strange ways. Read exclusively through curses.

In your last program, you read input up to EOF. Subsequent input is therefore EOF.